# Start two jars into same kubernetes container sequentially

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I want to deploy Java microservice in kubernetes container. I am bundling APM agent to this microservice by passing JAVA_TOOL_OPTION as environment variable and mention jar file path for APM agent.
The problem is when I include APM agent with microservice, it takes 100 seconds to start.
Is there any way I can decouple microservice and APM agent, and run in same kubernetes container.
I want to reduce the start time for microservice as APM agent is causing startup delay.
Can you advise how can I start the microservice , wait for 2 min, and then start APM agent.
Is there any downside of this approach?

Comment: What APM agent are you using?

Comment: @gohm'c CA APM agent for performancec monitoring

Comment: how does the APM agent interact with the microservice application? is it by using network connection (ex: accessing a port in the app)?